# Does Chrome browser support GWT 2.5?

Tags: gwt, google-chrome, gwt-2.5

I've recently gone through the following link:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/release-notes#Release_Notes_Current

There's a point under title : **Breaking Changes and Other Changes of Note**

***GWT no longer supports ChromeFrame. The implementation caused more bugs than it solved.***

Does this mean that Chrome browser won't support GWT 2.5? Or am I misunderstood? Can anyone explain this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ChromeFrame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) is a plugin for Internet Explorer that uses Chrome's rendering and JavaScript engine instead of IE's equivalents. So this statement does not refer to the standalone Chrome browser (and it would be strange indeed if it did).

Comment: Particularly as there's a DevMode plugin for Chrome, and SuperDevMode has been demoed with Chrome at I/O, being the only browser that supports SourceMaps ;-)

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT** Google confirms an error in the release notes: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit-contributors/wzilCaLySCU/aYMwD2zzOrsJ

This is probably related to http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6665

Technically, there should be nothing special to support ChromeFrame (which is *not* the same as Chrome, so to answer your question: yes you're misunderstanding that statement from the release notes).

Actually, I believe the release notes are wrong: GWT 2.4 had issues with ChromeFrame (actually, when it was installed but disabled), and this has been fixed in 2.5 (see link to issue above).
I'll get in touch with Google to know more about it and possibly have the release notes fixed (if the above is right). **Edit:** [done](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/wzilCaLySCU/discussion) (will contact some directly by mail if needed).

Answer (score 1):

[ChromeFrame is a plugin for other browsers than Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/chrome-frame-faq#TOC-What-is-Google-Chrome-Frame-)